# Continuity and uniform continuity of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Real Analysis experts ,

I have learnt that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is not uniformly continuous on $0<z\le1$.

My question is:

Is $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ uniformly continuous on $0<z<1?$

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: The problematic point is $0$. The same proof for the case $(0,1]$ would work for the case $(0,1)$ also.

Comment: Proof is given using epsilon delta definition. Can you tell me whats geometrical problem with "0" ?

Comment: Uniformly continuous  function should have continuous continuation on closure of set.

Comment: what will happen if f is a complex valued function and $0<|z|<1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\left|f\left(\frac 1 {2^n}\right)-f\left(\frac 1 {2^{n+1}}\right)\right|=2^n$.

Comment: Someone mentioned that the problem id sue to 0? but how ?

Comment: For every $c>0$ there exists an integer $n$ such that $|{1\over 2^n}-{1\over 2^{n+1}}|<c$, but $|f({1\over 2^n})-f({1\over 2^{n+1}})|>1$.

Answer (score 0):

A useful theorem, A continuous function on $(a,b)$ , where $a,b \in \mathbb{R} $  is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ **iff** $\lim_{x \to a+ } f(x) $ and $\lim_{x \to b- } f(x) $ exists finitely.

In your problem, $\lim_{z\to 0+ } \frac{1}{z} \to +\infty $

**Edit**: similar case also for complex valued function, if  a complex valued function $f$ is continuous on the region $a \lt |z| \lt b $ , then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $a \lt |z| \lt b $  iff $\lim_{z \to z_{0} } f(z) $ exist finitely, where $z_{0} $ runs over all limit points of the region $\{z : a \lt |z| \lt b \} $ ,

You can check that $\lim_{z \to 0 } \frac{1}{z} $ doesn't exist if we approach $0$ along real line,

Comment: will you please also discuss th ecase if f is complex valued

Comment: @Taj I did edit.

Comment: So f(z)=1/z is not uniformly continuous on all of these 0<|z|<1, 0  \leq |z| <1, 0<|z| \leq 1,

Comment: Hmmm, .........

Answer (score 0):

For a more geometrical approach, see the intuitive example [provided by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity):

[image]

In the above GIF, the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous. This is because the graph of $f(x)$ escapes the top and/or bottom of the $\text{height}\times \text{width} = 2\varepsilon \times 2\delta$ window irregardless of how small $\delta$ is. In contrast, the function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous as it never escapes the box.

---

The function $f(z)=1/z$ is continuous everywhere it's defined, that is, everywhere except $z=0$.

But it's not uniformly continuous in a punctured neighborhood of $0$. In fact, it's the standard example of a function that's continuous on the open interval $(0,1)$
but not uniformly continuous there.

By contradiction, suppose that $f(z)$ is uniformly continuous in the region $0<|z|<1.$ Then, for all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a $0<\delta<1$ such that $|z_1-z_2 |<\delta \implies \left|f(z_1)-f(z_2)\right|<\varepsilon$ where $z_1,z_2$ are arbitrary elements in the domain of $f$.

Let $z_1=\delta$ and $z_2=\delta/(1+\varepsilon)$. Then

$$|z_1 - z_2| = \frac{\delta\varepsilon}{1 + \epsilon} < \delta,$$
but
$$\left|f(z_1) - f(z_2)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{\delta}-\frac{1 + \epsilon}{\delta} \right| = 
\frac{\epsilon}{\delta} > \epsilon,$$
which is a direct contradiction to the definition of uniform continuity. Therefore, $f(z)$ is not uniformly continuous on the unit punctured disk.